# Powershell: web-request with relevant info

Tags: powershell, html-parsing, invoke-webrequest

I would like to print text from webpage https://cicero.blazni.cz/lipsum.php . This page generates words when its loaded. It works fine if the page is loaded in browser, powershell prints the sentence which is changed every 5s. If I close browser, the page is not loaded and invoke-request get just the last sentence loaded.

Is there the way to "run" php and than download information?
Or another way to get different result everytime I run my code?

```
$page  = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://cicero.blazni.cz/lipsum.php
$reading = $page.parsedhtml.getElementById("rightcol").firstChild.innerhtml
$reading
```

I hope my question is understandable. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is not obvious what you are trying to, please explain it further.  Is your powershell script on a different machine to the php code ?

Comment: @RohitGupta There is the webpage, which generates random sentences (every 5s). I would like to get fresh new sentence using powershell if I invoke webrequest to webpage. It works, if the browser with page is open, powershell code get new sentence via my code. But if I close the browser, somehow I get just the last printed sentence. How to make my code work even when browser is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell **cmdlets** are .NET code that don't exist in the filesystem.  Execution is passed to the application - in this case the browser.

> A PowerShell cmdlet is a lightweight **command** that is used in the Windows PowerShell environment.
>
> The public properties that define the parameters that are available to the user or to the **application** that is running the cmdlet.

[PowerShell Module Cmdlets and Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/host-integration-server/core/powershell-module-cmdlets-and-commands)

I am piecing this together so I can't give you all the references.

The step-by-step process is here to stop this, I don't want to plagiarize it.
[How to use Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell without having to first open Internet Explorer](https://blog.dhampir.no/content/how-to-use-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell-without-having-to-first-open-internet-explorer)

Disclaimer, I have no affiliation with this site.

Comment: Wow. There is whole new world in this information! 
Before I will try the code, I checked if the webpage runs on IE - and it doesnt. Will it affect solution?

Comment: And also: it seems that "Set-ItemProperty ..... -Value 1" means just: load the homepage straight away, what does it mean for my link?
info from here: https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_7_2008R2&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::NoFirstRunCustomise_1